Buscar valores en un objeto y reemplazarlos por otro
Me ha surgido una duda con respecto a esto, genero un arreglo mediante un objeto de una consulta, el detalle es que hay algunos valores que la base de datos tienen "0" o NUll.
Este es el objeto que obtengo y guardo en un array search.
{
    CT: "07KTV02X", 
    BBSUC: "2531", 
    BBDIST: "0", 
    BNOM: null, 
    BCVE: "2531"
}

Lo que deseo es iterar dicho arreglo y encontrar esos valores para sustituirlos con un "-" o "sin datos", esto para enviarlo al cliente y solo pintarlo.
    if(isset($_POST['search'])){
        $busqueda = $_POST['search'];

    /***********************************************************/
        $stid = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT A.CT, A.BBSUC, A.DISTANCIA BBDIST, B.NOM_SUCURSAL BNOM, C.*,
        FROM TABLA A, TABLA B, TABLA C, TABLA D 
        WHERE C.CT =  '$busqueda' AND A.CT = C.CT AND C.CT = D.CT(+)
        AND A.BBSUC = B.CVE_SUC");
        oci_execute($stid);

        $search = array();
        while(($row = oci_fetch_object($stid)) != false){
            $search = $row; 
        }
      $searchP = array_replace(null, "Sin datos", $search);

      $infoComplete = array($searchP);
      echo json_encode($infoComplete, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
     }


Ya lo intente con str_replace o array_replace y otros métodos, pero no lo logro.
    $searchP = $hw_modifyobject( $search,null, "Sin datos");

    $searchP = array_replace(null, "Sin datos", $search);

También:
    foreach ($search as $val) {
        if($val == null || $val=="" ||$val== "0"){
            $val = $val = "Sin datos";
        }
    }


¿Has leído la documentación de array_replace?. array_replace necesita de al menos 2 argumentos tipo array: el array a modificar y el array donde se hará la búsqueda de la llave para ser reemplazada por el valor. En el caso del foreach, ¿qué intentas hacer en esta línea: $val = $val = "Sin datos";?

Entiendo @aeportugal me colapse al no poder obtener lo que quería, pero ya lo solucione.

Pata utilizar  el foreach  recuerda que debes hacerlo de la siguiente manera
  foreach ($search as $key => $val) {
          if($val == null || $val=="" ||$val== "0"){
            $search->$key  = "Sin datos";
        }
    }

var_dump($search);

Como lo tenias  val era el key y  solo sustituiría el índice 0

Gracias por tu ayuda, tuve un colapso mental de tanto buscar soluciones y tan sencillo que era.
